# Umbraco Publishing Issues

Tags: azure, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm having issues publishing on Umbraco sites.

It would seem to me as if its a caching issue but I can't get to the root of the problem.

I have been able to recreate the issue but it does seem to be intermittent.

Example:

1. Create new page - populate data
2. Save & Publish page
3. View page in same browser, working fine and content correct.
4. View page in alternative browser and the page cannot be found.

I have:

- republished the entire site
- deleted the umbraco.config files
- re-indexed the site
- restarted the App Pool

None of these work.. But come back the next day the updates are working.

Umbraco 7, Hosted on Azure

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the site load balanced? If so, it's possible that changes aren't being replicated across all copies of the site?

Comment: Oh my days. How stupid am I, I'd setup load balancing ages ago on this azure plan.. I'd been reading all the blog posts mentioning load balancing dismissing it because I was thinking this site wasn't load balanced.. Thanks Tim, I'm an idiot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Scaling was causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, disabling auto scaling in Azure 'DefaultServerFarm' was my solution too - but more specifically: after modifying that setting I made sure to set the number of instances to 1 ! Leaving it at 2 would result in the same issue.